# How to find a series of numbers that scale exponentially to reach a desired number

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, exponential-function

4 – 15,000,000      
3 – 1,350,000 * (3 * 4) = 16,200,000 **<--Trying to make this 15,000,000**       
2 – 225,000 * (3 * 2) = 1,350,000             
1 – 75,000 * (3 * 1) = 225,000

I am having difficulties trying to find a series of numbers that scale exponentially (can't be linear) to multiply by, that will allow me to reach  15,000,000 exactly from a starting point of 75,000. How do I calculate this?

Comment: What are you allowed to change? Also, please look up Mathjax, and format your equations.

Comment: @Andrei I can change anything but the top (15,000,000) and bottom (75,000) numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to me like you want After step $i$ to have $75000 r^i$. Then after three steps you have $75000 r^3=1500000$. Then $r=\sqrt[3]{15000000/75000}\approx 5.848$. Then  after the first step you get $438600$, after step 2 you have $2564932.8$, and after step 3 you have $14999727.0$.

Comment: It amazes me how I get down-voted, but then someone smart enough comes along that intuitively understands what I'm trying to do and successfully answers my question. Thank you sir.